# Modify an HTML element from one component in another component in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-ref

I create todoapp and I would like to create a button that, when clicked, will modify the list to display only completed tasks.
I have three components:
`App.js` - it's a main component, `TasksList.js` - is responsible for displaying tasks(initially it displays all tasks), `ListHandler`- I want to create the aforementioned button here.
I decided to use useRef to be able to access the list of tasks (ul with class tasksWrapper in `TasksList`) anywhere.
`App.js`:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import "./sass/main.css";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Browser from "./components/Browser";
import TasksList from "./components/TasksList";
import ListHandler from "./components/ListHandler";

function App() {
  //set default date for initial tasks
  let defaultDate = new Date().toTimeString();
  defaultDate = defaultDate.split(" ")[0];

  const [tasksList, setTasksList] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      content: "embrace Java",
      done: false,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "find a job in my dream industry",
      done: true,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "win a war",
      done: false,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
  ]);

  const tasksListWrapper = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Browser tasksList={tasksList} />
      <TasksList
        tasksList={tasksList}
        setTasksList={setTasksList}
        tasksListWrapper={tasksListWrapper} />
      <ListHandler
        tasksList={tasksList}
        setTasksList={setTasksList}
        tasksListWrapper={tasksListWrapper} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`TasksList.js` returned JSX (`displayTasks("all")` just returns < li > with task.content for every task :

```
return (
<section className="tasksList">
  <h2>LIST</h2>
  <ul ref={tasksListWrapper} className="tasksWrapper">{displayTasks("all")} 
  </ul>
</section>);
```

`ListHandler` button and function `displayDoneTasks` responsible for displaying completed tasks:

```js
const displayDoneTasks = () => {
    const returnDoneTasks = () => {
      return tasksList.map((task) => {
        if (task.active && task.done) {
          return (
            <li
              key={task.id}
              className="task"
              id={task.id}
            >
              {task.content}
            </li>
          );
        } else return null;
      });
    };
    console.log(returnDoneTasks());
    tasksListWrapper.current.innerHTML = returnDoneTasks(); //if task.done === true then output is: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "li", key: "0", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
  }

  return (
    <section className="listHandler">
      >
      <button className="doneTasks" onClick={() => displayDoneTasks()}>
        Show only completed tasks
      </button>
      
    </section>
  );
```

Why isn't `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "li", key: "0", ref: null, props: {…}, …}` displayed as HTML elements? Maybe my solution is wrong and I should have done it in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another state variable `showCompleted` and allow child component (`ListHandler`) to modify it by passing function as a prop.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import "./sass/main.css";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Browser from "./components/Browser";
import TasksList from "./components/TasksList";
import ListHandler from "./components/ListHandler";

function App() {
  //set default date for initial tasks
  let defaultDate = new Date().toTimeString();
  defaultDate = defaultDate.split(" ")[0];

  const [tasksList, setTasksList] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      content: "embrace Java",
      done: false,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "find a job in my dream industry",
      done: true,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "win a war",
      done: false,
      active: true,
      date: defaultDate,
    },
  ]);
 
  // const tasksListWrapper = useRef(); not needed

  const [showCompleted, setShowCompleted] = useState(false);

  // display all tasks or only completed based on showCompleted state
  const tasksToShow = !showCompleted ? tasksList : tasksList.filter(
    task => task.active && task.done
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Browser tasksList={tasksToShow} />
      <TasksList
        tasksList={tasksToShow}
        setTasksList={setTasksList} />
      <ListHandler
        tasksList={tasksToShow}
        setTasksList={setTasksList}
        setShowCompleted={setShowCompleted} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`ListHandler` needs to call the function passed as `setShowCompleted` prop.

```
function ListHandler({ setShowCompleted }) {
  return (
    <section className="listHandler">
      <button className="doneTasks" onClick={() => setShowCompleted(true)}>
        Show only completed tasks
      </button>
      
    </section>
  );
}
```

It will cause state update in `App` and will re-calculate `tasksToShow` by picking only those tasks which are complete which in turn will be passed to `TasksList` for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can edit another component directly without using document. However if it is a parent or child is it easy to send in methods in props which can be used to modify state which in that case rerenders the component.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you are seeing is because you are looking at React JSX elements rather than HTML DOM nodes.

Your approach here is just really wrong.  You never want to use `.innerHTML` to override other content that you yourself generated with React.  You want to update the props and state such you are generating the correct content.

In fact your `ListHandler` already has access to a prop `setTasksList` which it could use to update the list shown by `TasksList`.  That's not *exactly* what you want in this particular case because setting the `tasksList` to a subset would cause the other tasks to be lost.  But that's the general approach.

What you want here is for the shared parent `App` to store some sort of state related to the filtering.  A simple `boolean` state might look like this:

```
const [showDone, setShowDone] = useState(false);
```

Provide the `TasksList` with a tasks array that reflects the current filtering (either all tasks or done tasks).  Provide the `ListHandler` with a function that it can call to update the filter.

Comment: So methods from pure js to modify the DOM like appendChild or createElement are not allowed in React?

Comment: Technically they are *allowed* but React provides better ways of doing these things.  It uses what's called the "Virtual DOM" as an layer between you and the DOM itself: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html  Appending a child to some `div` is going to yield unpredictable results if the whole component that created that `div` is re-rendered.  Mutating the DOM directly goes against the principles of React where `props` and `state` are used to generate DOM elements.